# PHP Notice - Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php

I'm still pretty new with PHP. I saw other posts about this notice, but none seemed to speak to my situation. I am attempting to list the Titles (h2 element) from another page. While I have succeeded in that endeavor (the titles are listing), I am also getting the following Notice:

'Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Users/jessenichols/Sites/HCS/news.php on line 26'

```
<?php
        function getTitle($Url){
            $str = file_get_contents($Url);
            if(strlen($str)>0){
                preg_match("/\<h2\>(.*)\<\/h2\>/",$str,$title);
                return $title[1];
            }
        }
        if ($handle = opendir('news')) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                    echo '<p class="article_selector">'.getTitle('news/'."$entry").'</p>';
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: For background info... Line 26 is the line 'return $title[1];'

Comment: When you do `return $title[1]`, on one of the iterations of your `while` loop, that regex isn't matching. Therefore you're trying returning something that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `getTitle` method, check if `$title[1]` is set, case not return null, then in your `while` loop, assign the result from `getTitle()` to variable and check if this variable is not null, like this

```
<?php
        function getTitle($Url){
            $str = file_get_contents($Url);
            if(strlen($str)>0){
                preg_match("/\<h2\>(.*)\<\/h2\>/",$str,$title);

                // if $title[1] isn't set, return null
                return isset($title[1]) ? $title[1] : null;
            }
        }
        if ($handle = opendir('news')) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                    // first, get the title
                    $title = getTitle('news/'.$entry);

                    // and after check if title is not null
                    if (null != $title) {
                        echo '<p class="article_selector">'.$title.'</p>';
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    ?>
```